# Using Google AdWords Conversion Tracking in Meteor

Tags: meteor, google-ads-api, conversion-tracking

I want to embed the Google Adwords Conversion Tracking Code into my Meteor app:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = XXX;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "XXXX";
var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* <![CDATA[ */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"></script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/XXXX/?label=XXXX&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

I tried to put it right into the html code of a template and I tried to append it to the html after the template rendered:

```
Template.success_page.rendered = function () {
    $("body").append(
        '.....');
}
```

Both ways do not work. The Tag Assistant Chrome Plugin gives me the error "No HTTP response detected". 
And on the browser console I can see

"Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened."

How do I have to embed it to make it work?

Comment: If you're using iron-router, have you looked at https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/iron-router-ga ? I haven't used it personally but it looks like it might help...

Comment: I am using that package for google analytics and it is working fine. But it does not handle adwords conversion tracking codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just integrated it using this:
https://developers.google.com/adwords-remarketing-tag/asynchronous/

It is coming from a remarketing perspective, but the conversion tag and the remarketing tag are basically the same thing.
Just set "google_remarketing_only" to false

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I inserted in in my <head> "<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js" charset="utf-8"></script>" and then simply do anywhere "window.google_trackConversion({
  google_conversion_id: xxx, 
  ....
});"

Comment: Where do you put the `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`?  I assume you can't download this and add it to your client `lib` folder because you want it to dynamically load with Google's latest code.